# MainActivity cannot rotate screen normally

Tags: android, rotation

My app's `MainActivity` behaves strangely in rotating screen. It cannot rotate itself until I click "overview" on Navigation bar and turn back on phones(tested on Nexus 4/5/6). However, it can rotate normally on tablets(Nexus 7/9) at any time.

Here are some properties for `MainActivity` I considered ***maybe*** influence screen rotation:

1. supports RTL
2. no `android:configChanges` in manifest.xml
3. using `RecyclerView` with `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` whose count of span changes according to screen size(3 above 7.0 and 2 below, the judgement occurs in `onCreate()`)
4. using `NavigationView` in design library
5. have a `Application`(customized) member assigned by `(MyApplication) getActivity` in `onCreate()`
6. `android:windowBackground="@android:color/transparent"` and `android:windowIsTranslucent="true"` in styles.xml

Please give some suggestions or directions to find out why the problem occurs. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** **set `android:screenOrientation="user(by default is unspecified)"` in manifest.xml will solve the problem but I really want to know why it can't rotate the screen without doing this.**